# Font-awesome doesn't work in Flask?

Tags: python, css, web, flask

I'm trying to use font-awesome to show small icons in my web pages.
My project is based on Flask framework.

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<!-- use bootstrap -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='custom.css')}}" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" type="text/css">
```

```
<a href="https://github.com/penguin-penpen" target="_blank"><i class="icon-github"></i> </a>
```

However, the icon does not appear.
My static file structure is:

```
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── images
│   ├── js
│   ├── less
│   └── scss
└── templates
```

I've also tested that in the browser the css file can be successfully loaded and my OS is OSX.

Comment: You'll probably have to do some in-browser debugging. Are the links being properly created? Can you load the files that they point to?

Comment: @Chris Yes, the css file can be successfully  loaded in browser. So I suppose it is not the matter with links. ;)

Comment: Could you show us the `static` folder structure? And what's your system platform(Linux, Windows or MAC OS)?

Comment: @lord63.j I've edited the question. Could you please give me some advice? Thanks!

Comment: @PenguinGoHack Check my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there are two problems:

1. if you want to use the github icon, you should use:

   ```
    <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
   ```

You can check the github icon on font-awesome here: [fa-github](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/github/)

2. it seems that you're using the font-awesome css, however, you should note that only one css file is not enough, you should copy the **entire** directory to the `static` folder as the documentation says:

> 1. Copy the entire font-awesome directory into your project.
> 2. In the `<head>` of your html, reference the location to your font-awesome.min.css.

you can find it here: [Get Started - EASY: Default CSS](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/)

---

A minimal example:

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`templates/index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><i class='fa fa-github'></i> Hello github</p>
  <body>
</html>
```

The `static` folder:

```
static
  |_ font-awesome
          |_ css
          |     |_  font-awesome.min.css
          |     |_...
          |...
```

Or you can just use the CDN, it's the easiest way to use font-awesome.

Comment: Yeah, I find it is the file structure's problem. Now it works well under your instruction! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I had to include 'all.min.css' instead of 'fontawesome.min.css' to see the right icons, otherwise, I was seeing weird icons.

Answer (score 1):

These are the icons for font-awesome: [Font Awesome icons](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)

Change your HTML to:

```
<a href="https://github.com/penguin-penpen" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github"></i> </a>
```

Comment: Actually I've tried this but it shows nothing. I was wondering whether there's something wrong with the path of the css file. I have a css directory in my 'static' directory, and all my css file, for example `bootstrap.min.css`, are put together in one directory.

Comment: It could be your syntax, try: `{{url_for('static', filename='css/font-awesome.min.css')}}` with no spaces around the `=`

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
<i class="fa fa-github"></i>
```

Comment: Actually I've tried this but it shows nothing. I was wondering whether there's something wrong with the path of the css file. I have a css directory in my 'static' directory, and all my css file, for example `bootstrap.min.css`, are put together in one directory.

Answer (score 0):

you must edit your all.css (awesomefont)
change the
    url(../bla/bla)
 to 
    url({{url_for(....)}}
and dont forget to include awesome font js(all.js)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the only solution I've found was to install the [Flask-FontAwesome](https://github.com/heartsucker/flask-fontawesome) package.

Answer (score 0):

you should use [Flask-FontAwesome](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-FontAwesome/#description) python package.

```
pip install Flask-FontAwesome
```

---

Applied to your example:

`app.py` :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_fontawesome import FontAwesome

app = Flask(__name__)
FontAwesome(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`templates/index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    {{ fontawesome_css() }}
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><i class='fa fa-github'></i> Hello github</p>
    {{ fontawesome_js() }}
  <body>
</html>
```

---

**Noticed :**

this package uses FontAwesome version 4.

To use the latest version of FontAnsome, you must update the contents of the `static` directory of the Flask-FontAwesome package (use `pip show Flask-FontAwesome` to find its location) by replacing its contents with the latest versions, cf [Download Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/download)